# Resolving "Out of memory" error in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to load a 340MB .mat file (Which is already divided into 6 different matrcies) but i keep getting "Out of memory" error for some of the sub-matrices.

Running the "Memory" command I get:

```
Maximum possible array:    133 MB (1.395e+08 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:    820 MB (8.597e+08 bytes) **
Memory used by MATLAB:    886 MB (9.294e+08 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):   3326 MB (3.488e+09 bytes)
```

So if considering the data division, it should be fine...

I use the following command:

> load('file.mat', 'X');

and it works fine. But when I load another file of the same size of X  I get the error.

thanks!

Comment: It might be a memory fragmentation problem. Try restarting Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Mathworks addresses our of memory problems in genereal in their documentation center, see http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html